# Can't select multiple values in a select

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, select, groovy

I use selenium for testing my webgui. This contains following method:

```
protected static selectListItems(String id, String value1, String value2, String value3,String value4){
    String values = ""

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value1))
        values += "\"" + value1 + "\""

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value2))
        values += ",\"" + value2 + "\""

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value3))
        values += ",\"" + value3 + "\""

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value4))
        values += ",\"" + value4 + "\""

    ((JavascriptExecutor) browser.driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('"+ id +"').value=[" + values + "];")
}
```

This groovy method puts selected values to a select on my weg page. I use the method like the following:

> selectListItems("queryASLevel","AccountStatement",null,null,null)

This works, when I try to add 2 items like the following

> selectListItems("queryASLevel","AccountStatement","AccountStatementDetail",null,null)

Than my result is only an empty String. How does this come and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting your method to be a bit groovier, it's probably `isNotBlank` failing:

```
protected static selectListItems(String id, String value1, String value2, String value3,String value4){
    String values = [value1, value2, value3, value4]
        .findAll()
        .collect { /"$it"/ }
        .join( ", " )
    String script = "document.getElementById('$id').value=[$values];"
    ((JavascriptExecutor)browser.driver).executeScript(script)
}
```

Comment: Seems a good answer, but when I debug in my second test case and I write document.getElementById("queryASLevel").value in the console, I receive a "", which indicates an empty string. Do you know how this comes?

Comment: No idea, print out `script` before the `executeScript` line...  I suspect some other factor is breaking things

Answer (score -1):

```
        function selectListItems()
        {
            var values="";
            for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
            {
                values += ""+arguments[i]+",";
            }
            alert(values);
        }
        selectListItems("sam","sffsdf","",null);
```

Argument object contains an array of the arguments. in this way we get value in form of arrays so we also get null value and empty string.